# Неправильно строится график репутации в профиле

Tags: дефект

Это мой график роста репутации:

[image: график репутации]

Как видим, по графику в марте было 9,1к. Но это не так. 10к я заработал 30 или 31 декабря 2019. Этому можно найти косвенное подтверждение [в статистике участников](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/609/year/ru-stackoverflow), где написано, что в 2020 я заработал 5696 репутации. 15,7к (сейчас) минус 5,6 (за 2020) как раз дает 10к.

Comment: График правильный, там с расположением названия месяцев проблема. Если обратить на конец, то он уже как бы соответствует примерно январю/февралю 2021. Вот [сюда](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269327/339911) обратите внимание.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ понятно. Как-то неаккуратно сделано.

Comment: Ещё вот [такое](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9504/176217) бывало :)